# How to send the same notification for 17th day of every month and customize it for a specific month

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I would like to set a constant notification for 17th day of every month -DEC 17th, MAY 17th, JUN 17th etc-. I would like to customize the notification whenever the month is March.

This is for an app that I am building for a request. Building it in Swift 4, for iOS. I haven't started to build yet, I checked a few questions here and there, couldn't get the result I expect.

The expected output is:

17th day of every month except March, notification should say "here's the monthly reminder for you". Every March, it should say "here's the yearly reminder for you"

Comment: You can do this by creating LocalNotification.. just round the loop and set the fireTime whichever you want.

Comment: Another way is by adding calendar event by setting EKEvent object to eventStore

Comment: Questions that show no effort from the OP should be closed.